# I am setting a property using setState before dispatching an action, but the property is not set in the redux action on dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a class component as follows,

```
  class PassengerAddPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    passenger: {
      flightNumber: "",
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      address: "",
      dob: "",
      passportNumber: ""
    }
  };
```

I will populate all the fields from form data that user enters, except flightNumber, which will be taken from url param, "this.props.match.params.flightNumber". The handleSubmit for the form is as follows,

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.props.match.params.flightNumber); //prints AH001
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        flightNumber: this.props.match.params.flightNumber
      },
      () => console.log(this.state.passenger) //prints empty
    ); 
    this.props.dispatch(passengerActions.addPassenger(this.state.passenger));
}
```

Even though I set the flightNumber, it will still show as empty in the Redux store (After dispatching the action, object recieved in the action will contain empty value for flightNumber property).

Please help. I am new to ReactJS and JS.

Comment: Are you getting flightNumber from `this.props.match.params.flightNumber` in `handleSubmit`?

Comment: Yes @ZainUlAbideen

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen, edited the question with console log statements

Comment: You won't get the result in the second console, as `setState` is async call.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen, edited the question with a callback method to console log, still it shows empty.

Comment: flightNumber does not exist in your state instead it exists in passenger state. Updated my answer.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen, you are awesome. This was the issue. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: Welcome buddy, Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reasons could be for:**

> it will still show as empty in the Redux store

1) You are using `this.setState` for setting state, which sets the local state of the component not global state in the Redux.

2) You are immediately trying to get `flightNumber` but it won't set as `setState` is an async call.

**Solution for 1):**

Only way to change the state in redux store is to dispatch an action with the data you want to change. For example:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
event.preventDefault();
this.props.dispatch({type: CHANGE_FLIGHT_NUMBER, flightNumber: flightNumber: this.props.match.params.flightNumber})
}
```

In Reducer:

```
case CHANGE_FLIGHT_NUMBER:
     return {...state, flightNumber: action.flightNumber}
```

**Solution for 2):**

Pass callback to `setState`:

```
this.setState(
  {
    passenger: {...this.state.passenger, flightNumber: this.props.match.params.flightNumber}
  },
  () => {
     console.log(this.state.passenger)
  }
)
```

Assumptions made while writing this answer:

1) You are passing state as `(state = initialState, action)` to your reducer function.

2) In your store there is state called `flightNumber` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Since setState is async, use the call back syntax of setState

```
    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          flightNumber: this.props.match.params.flightNumber
        },
       ()=>
       {               
         this.props.dispatch(passengerActions.addPassenger(this.state.passenger));
       });
    }
```

Comment: The flightNumber is still in the action object